# Printing the contents of an Array with a Class Method

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, printing

I am trying to return the contents of a two dimensional array of 'room' objects as a kind of print/display of what's in the array.

```
Room* m_map[10][10];
```

A scatter of rooms is generated like so:

```
//Initialise array to NULL
for(int x=0;x<10;x++)
{
    for(int y=0;y<10;y++)
        m_map[x][y] = NULL;
}

for(int n=0; n<10; n++)
{       
    for(int ran=0; ran<3; ran++)
    {
        int r_n = rand() % 10 ;

        Room* r = new Room(n, "Normal", true, false, false, true);
        m_map[r_n][n] = r;
    }       

}
```

I'd then like to display/print for the user where these rooms are, in reference to the NULL.

So I could for example if NULL display '#', if it's a Room Leave a ' '.

I'm unsure of the bit I should return in the declaration of the method?

Any help or pointing in the right direction would really be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a method for printing the array to your class:

```
void print() const 
{
  for(int n=0; n<10; ++n)
  {       
    for(int m=0; m<10; ++m)
    {
      std::cout << m_map[n][m] ? : "# " : ". ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't answer the question I was after. It's the return bit that I don't know how to do. Because this is a class method it needs a return type. I am thinking of doing what you've just done in a stringbuilder like structure and returning a string, unless you could reccomend anything else?

Comment: @Springfox the connection between returning an array (which has been answered in your previous question) and printing the array isn't at all clear.

Comment: I agree with juan. Otherwise I believe you want a string representation of the array and you want to return it? That's kind of useless unless you want to serialize or write it to a file.

Comment: I want to be able to output a visual representation in some way of what exists in the generated array of rooms or m_map[10][10]

Comment: @Springfox that sounds like what the function provided in the answers does.

Comment: Aaah, I see I somehow wasn't aware I could use cout like that in a method, I thought I had to return it through a method and take it that way. :$. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Loop trough both dimensions. Everytime you loop trough x display all the rooms within a column and append a comma afterwards.

When reaching the end of a row and moving on to the next row simply append a line break to print the next column's on a new line.

```
void MyClass::printMap(unsigned int numOfRows, unsigned int numOfCols)
{
  using std;
  for(unsigned int y = 0; y < numOfRows ; y++)
  {
    for(unsigned int x = 0; x < numOfCols ; x++)
    {
       if(m_map[y][x] == NULL)
          cout << # << ",";
       else
          cout << m_map[y][x].roomName() << ",";   
    }

    cout << endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay this works for getting them, but from the class methods how can I return this? As a string builder like formation? Or..?

Comment: There's no need to return anything. You need to have a class named "MyClass" with a reference to the array you are trying to print. The "cout" call will print anything you give it to the output stream, which in your case will probably be the console.

Comment: I had no idea I could use a method like that, I'm just now getting it so it shows as a 10 x 10 grid as apposed to a line of characters and I'll be really happy with that. :)